# How to convert multiple lists from scraped website to dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I scraped a website with multiple pages which contain table data. Now I have the data as multiple lists. How do I convert the lists to a dataframe?

```
url = 'https://www.insolvencydirect.bis.gov.uk/fip1/Home/Search'
session = requests.Session()

def make_initial_request():
  page = session.post(url, {'IPForename' : '', 'IPSurname' : '', 'IPCompany' : '', 'IPTown' : '', 'IPNumber' : '', 'IPCounty' : ''})
  get_page_content(page, True)

def get_page_content(page, show_header):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  #print(soup)
  results = soup.find_all('tr')
  lists = results
  if show_header == False:
      lists = results[1:]
  for row in lists:
    IP_data = get_attributes(row)
    print(IP_data)

def make_requests_for_pages(i):
  page = session.get(url + "?Page=" + str(i))
  get_page_content(page, False)

def get_attributes(table_row):
  soup = BeautifulSoup(str(table_row), 'html.parser')
  html_content = soup.get_text()
  if html_content:
    result = html_content.strip().split('\n')
    while len(result) < 8:
      result.append('')
    return result

First_page = make_initial_request()
for i in range(2, 3):
  Other_pages = make_requests_for_pages(i)
```

This is the output below. There are more lists, and every list contains data for one person. The first list with "Name", "Company" etc is what I will like to be the headers in the dataframe.

```
    ['Name', '', '', 'Company', '', '', 'Address', '', '', 'Telephone', '', '', 'Fax', '', '', 'Email', '', '', 'IP No', '', '', 'Authorising Body']
['Mr ROBERT SCHNEIDERMAN', '', '18 Downage, LONDON, NW4 1AH', '07770 783757', '', 'schneiderman@hotmail.co.uk', '8733', 'ICAEW']
['Mr SHAGUN S DUBEY', '', '63 Stanhope Avenue, LONDON, N3 3LY', '', '', 'dubeyss@yahoo.com', '9216', 'ICAEW']
['Mr NICK T C HILL', '11/F', 'Greenville, 2 Glenealy, HONG KONG', '07726 631 405', '', 'nickhill@cunana.com', '7239', 'ICAEW']
['Mr Daniel Allen', '360 Insolvency Limited', '1 Castle Hill Court, Castle Hill, ROCHESTER, Kent, ME1 1LF', '01634 475546', '', 'dannyallen@360insolvency.co.uk', '21334', 'ICAEW']
['Mr ANTHONY JOHN SARGEANT', 'A J Sargeant & Co Limited', '7 Newfield Court, 586 Fulwood Road, Sheffield, S10 3QE', '0114 268 1862', '', 'tony@ajsargeant.co.uk', '9659', 'ICAEW']
['Mr ALAN STUART BRADSTOCK', 'AABRS Limited', 'Langley House, Park Road, LONDON, N2 8EY', '0208 444 2000', '0208 444 3400', 'asb@aabrs.com', '5956', 'IPA']
['Mr KEVIN MCLEOD', 'AABRS Limited', 'Langley House, Park Road, LONDON, N2 8EY', '0208 444 3400', '', 'km@aabrs.com', '9438', 'ICAS']
['Mr DAVID SIMON MATTHEW EDWARDS', 'Aaron & Partners LLP', '5-7 Grosvenor Court, Foregate Street, CHESTER, CH1 1HG', '01244 405555', '01244 405566', 'simon.edwards@aaronandpartners.com', '8244', 'ICAEW']
['Mrs Janette Louise Chillery-Belcher', 'Aaron & Partners LLP', '5-7 Grosvenor Court, Foregate Street, CHESTER, CH1 1HG', '01244 405555', '', 'jan.chillery@aaronandpartners.com', '22172', 'ICAEW']
['Miss TRACY ANN TAYLOR', 'Abbey Taylor Ltd', "Unit 6, Twelve O'Clock Court, 21 Attercliffe Road, SHEFFIELD, S4 7WW", '0114 292 2402', '0114 292 2403', 'tracy.taylor@abbeytaylor.co.uk', '8899', 'ICAEW']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do build an dataframe like CSV you can do like this:

```
# i've created a list with all lists, if you do this just run my script, must run well
lists = [
    ['Name', '', '', 'Company', '', '', 'Address', '', '', 'Telephone', '', '', 'Fax', '', '', 'Email', '', '', 'IP No', '', '', 'Authorising Body'],
    ['Mr ROBERT SCHNEIDERMAN', '', '18 Downage, LONDON, NW4 1AH', '07770 783757', '', 'schneiderman@hotmail.co.uk', '8733', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Mr SHAGUN S DUBEY', '', '63 Stanhope Avenue, LONDON, N3 3LY', '', '', 'dubeyss@yahoo.com', '9216', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Mr NICK T C HILL', '11/F', 'Greenville, 2 Glenealy, HONG KONG', '07726 631 405', '', 'nickhill@cunana.com', '7239', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Mr Daniel Allen', '360 Insolvency Limited', '1 Castle Hill Court, Castle Hill, ROCHESTER, Kent, ME1 1LF', '01634 475546', '', 'dannyallen@360insolvency.co.uk', '21334', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Mr ANTHONY JOHN SARGEANT', 'A J Sargeant & Co Limited', '7 Newfield Court, 586 Fulwood Road, Sheffield, S10 3QE', '0114 268 1862', '', 'tony@ajsargeant.co.uk', '9659', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Mr ALAN STUART BRADSTOCK', 'AABRS Limited', 'Langley House, Park Road, LONDON, N2 8EY', '0208 444 2000', '0208 444 3400', 'asb@aabrs.com', '5956', 'IPA'],
    ['Mr KEVIN MCLEOD', 'AABRS Limited', 'Langley House, Park Road, LONDON, N2 8EY', '0208 444 3400', '', 'km@aabrs.com', '9438', 'ICAS'],
    ['Mr DAVID SIMON MATTHEW EDWARDS', 'Aaron & Partners LLP', '5-7 Grosvenor Court, Foregate Street, CHESTER, CH1 1HG', '01244 405555', '01244 405566', 'simon.edwards@aaronandpartners.com', '8244', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Mrs Janette Louise Chillery-Belcher', 'Aaron & Partners LLP', '5-7 Grosvenor Court, Foregate Street, CHESTER, CH1 1HG', '01244 405555', '', 'jan.chillery@aaronandpartners.com', '22172', 'ICAEW'],
    ['Miss TRACY ANN TAYLOR', 'Abbey Taylor Ltd', "Unit 6, Twelve O'Clock Court, 21 Attercliffe Road, SHEFFIELD, S4 7WW", '0114 292 2402', '0114 292 2403', 'tracy.taylor@abbeytaylor.co.uk', '8899', 'ICAEW']
]

dataFrame = ''
tmp_str = ''
quotedStr = lambda x: '"'+x+'"' if x != '' else ''
for lst in lists:
    tmp_str=''
    for element in lst: 
        if lst[len(lst)-1] == element:
            tmp_str += quotedStr(element)+'\n'
        else:
            tmp_str += quotedStr(element) + ','
    dataFrame+=tmp_str

# this dataFrame will be like an dataframe loaded from CSV file
print(dataFrame)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change these lines:

```
for row in lists:
    IP_data = get_attributes(row)
    print(IP_data)
```

to

```
IP_data = pd.DataFrame()  # declare somewhere before the loop
for row in lists:
    attributes = get_attributes(row)
    buffer = pd.DataFrame(
    [[
        attributes[0],
        attributes[1],
        #...etc
    ]],
    columns=['Name', 'Company', ...etc])
    IP_data = pd.concat([IP_data, buffer])
```